# Why it doesn't work clip-path only ios for foreginObject

Tags: css, ios, svg

I'm just trying to use **clip-path** in **svg** like this
`-webkit-clip-path: url(#clip_path20004);`

But, it seems like doesn't work only **iOS** any broswers, Safari, Chrome, whatever...

Because, in Mac, Android, the other OS works perfectly fine...

Here is my full code.

Please, give me some hint or advice and is welcoming!

Thank you reading!

Cheers,

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 679.9 640.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 679.9 640.2;" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#5A5B5B;}
    .st1{fill:#929292;}
    .st2{fill:#EEEEEE;}
    .st3{fill:#E46867;}
    .st4{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);}
    .st5{clip-path:url(#SVGID_5_);}
    .super {
        clip-path: url(#clip_path20004);
        -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip_path20004); 
    }
</style>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M649.4,0H30.5C13.7,0,0,13.7,0,30.5v464h679.9v-464C679.9,13.7,666.2,0,649.4,0z M650,416.9H29.9V35.8H650
        V416.9z"/>
    <path class="st1" d="M416.2,640.2H252l12.7-103h138.8L416.2,640.2z"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path class="st2" d="M433.6,628.5H234.7c-3.2,0-5.8,2.6-5.8,5.8l0,0c0,3.2,2.6,5.8,5.8,5.8h198.9c3.2,0,5.8-2.6,5.8-5.8l0,0
                C439.4,631.2,436.8,628.5,433.6,628.5z M0,494.6v31.8c0,16.8,13.7,30.5,30.5,30.5h618.9c16.8,0,30.5-13.7,30.5-30.5v-31.8
                L0,494.6L0,494.6z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path class="st3" d="M650,463H29.9v-46.8H650V463z"/>
    <g>
        <g>
            <path class="st2" d="M59.6,453.8h7.1V426h-7.1V453.8z M45.1,453.8h7.1V426h-7.1V453.8z M128.6,437.6c-0.9-3.7-4.2-6.4-8.1-6.4
                s-7.2,2.7-8.1,6.4h-11.7v3.9h11.7c0.9,3.7,4.2,6.4,8.1,6.4s7.2-2.7,8.1-6.4h488.1v-3.9H128.6z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
<g>
    <g>
        <clipPath id="clip_path20004">
            <rect id="clip_path20004" x="29.7" y="35.3" width="620.4" height="380.2"/>
        </clipPath>
        <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 -1.907350)" class="super">
                <image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new;" width="766" height="762" xlink:href="base64_string" transform="matrix(0.8099 0 0 0.8099 29.7703 -4.8974)">
            </image>
            <foreignObject x="10" y="70" width="900" height="600" transform="matrix(0.8099 0 0 0.8099 11.5619 -29.1255)">
                    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                        <iframe width="770" height="474" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6eitg6Bsqbk" title="YouTube video player">
                        </iframe>
                    </body>
                </foreignObject>
            <g transform="matrix(0.8099 0 0 0.8099 11.5619 -29.1255)">
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <defs>
                            <polygon id="SVGID_3_" points="13.5,70.9 14.5,70.9 13.5,71.9                            "/>
                        </defs>
                        <defs>
                            <polygon id="SVGID_4_" points="11.5,68.9 10.5,68.9 11.5,67.9                            "/>
                        </defs>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_5_">
                            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
                        </clipPath>
                        <clipPath id="SVGID_6_" class="st5">
                            <use xlink:href="#SVGID_4_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
                        </clipPath>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: FWIW iOS has one browser really. On iOS Chrome, Firefox etc are just shells on top of webkit. That's why these bugs reproduce on all browsers on iOS

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks a lot! I can understand more, thats why I've encountered this bug! and its quite interesting to see that I can only reproduce on iOS... 